# New Lead custom fields deployed, but not available when adding a new lead

Tags: apex, visualforce, workflow, salesforce2salesforce, workflowoutboundmessage

I just deployed a flow that depends on new custom fields I created for Leads,

The deployment was successful,

And I can see the new fields in Leads and the new Page layout in Leads,

But when I try to create a new Lead manually,

It does not show the new fields nor does it show the new page layout,

Of course when I run the flow, I get an error because of this,

I know why now,

But whats strange is, usually I get an email that tells me what the error is,

This time I did not get any emails,

Does someone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the new fields have no FLS (Field Level Security) set.  If you select the name of the new field when viewing the object, you will see a Field Level Security button at the top.  Make sure the visibility is checked for the profiles that need to see the field or run the flow.  For the page layout, you need to switch the layout to your new layout in the assign page layouts section of the object.